# mvc view model binding from different Model when call Create or Update Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, model

I am doing a MVC APP, I have a ModelView that have en Entity and a IList that it is populate in the Controller to fill an DropdownList.

This is my ViewModel

```html
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public Users user { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }
    }
```

```
User is a class
```

The Controller looks like this.

```html
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var countries = GetCountries();
              var model = new UserViewModel { AvailableCountries = countries };
            return View(model);
        }
```

The GetCountries is a Function that returns a list of Countries.

The View is a normal View that import from

```
@model TableAvivaVoz.Models.UserViewModel
```

The rest of the View, i do not think is important... each element Inherits from `model.user.`

The problem I found is when Submit the View. On Create Method, that looks like this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Country_id,Name,LastName,Sex,CodArea,PhoneNumber,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword")] Users user)
```

If my `Create` Method retuns a `UserViewModel` instance, all properties are null.

It get all the properties of User class, that it is part of my `UserViewModel` class.

But, if an error ocurrs, i do not how to call `AvailableCountries` method that returns a `UserViewModel` instance...

```html
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Country_id,Name,LastName,Sex,CodArea,PhoneNumber,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword")] Users user)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _db.Users.Add(user);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }
               
                UserViewModel.AvailableCountries = GetCountries();//error
                return View(user);
            }
```

My question, is how can i call `AvailableCountries` method when I have an instance or User instead or UserViewModel ?

thanks

This is my View...

```html
@model TableAvivaVoz.Models.UserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Users</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Country_id, "Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user.Country_id, Model.AvailableCountries, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Country_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nombre" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Apellido" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Sex, "Género", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Label("Hombre")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.user.Sex, "1", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.Label("Mujer")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.user.Sex, "0", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Sex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.CodArea, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.CodArea, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Cód Area" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.CodArea, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Número Telefono" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.user.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Contraseña" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.user.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Repetir Contraseña" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <label>Image</label>
                <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
            </div>
            @if (Model.user == null || Model.user.Picture == null)
            {
                <div class="form-control-static">No Image</div>
            }
            @*else
            {
                <img class="img-thumbnail" width="150" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product",new { Model.ProductID })" />
            }*@
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: actually your view is important, can you share so we can make changes to it. I think you would need to change so that you submit UserViewModel instead of just properties of User. and incase of error, we would send back UserViewModel (filling countries again) .

Comment: I added the View... In resume, the problem is that Create Inherit from User, and the return view recieves 'UserViewModel' Thanks

Comment: can you just not leave it upto auto bind and change post method to receive UserViewModel.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just change it so you leave it upto auto binding of mvc, which is much cleaner

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserViewModel model)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = new User();
                    user.FirstName = model.User.FirstName;
                    //........ rest of the properties here
                    _db.Users.Add(user);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }

                model.AvailableCountries = GetCountries();//error
                return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: What if there are properties on the User entity that you do not wish to be provided by the user? For example an `IsAdministrator` field? Such automatic binding to a model is a bad practice. You should either use a view model or explicitly specify the properties that you want to be coming from the outside.

Comment: thats why you would really need use UserViewModel and not directly inherit or user Entity. Just have properties that user should be able to edit. and not pass posted user directly to db.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the same `UserViewModel` from your Create action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Country_id,Name,LastName,Sex,CodArea,PhoneNumber,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword")] Users user)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Users.Add(user);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

        var model = new UserViewModel 
        { 
            user = user,
            AvailableCountries = GetCountries(),
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```